# how to test a the length of content in a p tag in rails unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I want to test the length of a string in a paragraph. Which method should I pick?
**assert_select 'dd p'.length, 80**
This is what I used, but it is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a helper to do that truncation and a test for the helper itself instead of using an integration test.

Suppose that the method is in your `users_helper.rb`

```
module UsersHelper
  def my_truncation(text)
    truncate(text, length: 80)
  end
end
```

Then you can add a test under `test/helpers` called `users_helper_test.rb` like following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def test_truncates_long_text
    assert(my_truncation("some text" * 200).size == 80)
  end

  def test_does_not_truncate_short_texts
    my_text = 'some text'
    assert(my_truncation(my_text).size == my_text.size)
  end
end
```

Then you can test it from the console:

```
ruby -I test test/helpers/users_helper_test.rb 
Run options: --seed 33686

# Running:

..

Finished in 0.179856s, 11.1200 runs/s, 11.1200 assertions/s.
```

Which runs muuuuuch faster than an integration test.
Hope this helps